# Prevent pens from falling out of shirt pocket

Tags: office-supplies, organization, adhesive

I'm a student and I like to carry my two pens on pocket of my shirt. However, occasionally I need to run. Sometimes I need to grovel for praying. How can I prevent them from falling out? They have holders as you can see from the image below. (I already read [the topic](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/6547/keep-pen-from-falling-out-of-pocket-or-attach-it-to-body-in-convenient-way) but it's slightly different case.)

[image]

Comment: After reading previous solutions, why didn't any of those work? What did you already try?

Comment: @Stan which of the anwers is related to the front pocket I mention?

Comment: I understand. You're a questioner (no answer - just another question) You are looking for a specific answer for your individual situation and NO other suggestion is adaptable or suitable for you for some reason.

Comment: You used the adhesive tag which means you prefer an answer that involves some kind of adhesive.

Comment: Some pens are better at staying in place than others. I posted an answer that helps the looser ones stay in, but is it possible to just switch to a different model of pen that would not give you this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, the length of the pen should be less than the length of the pocket. Secondly, the grip of the holder should be tight enough to hold the cloth of the pocket.

Comment: Does it prevent falling out while running?

Comment: @snr One experiment is worth 1000 expert opinions.

Answer (score 2):

**Pocket Pencil-Plunging Prevention Preparation Procedure**

This alliterative suggestion fulfills your requirement for a HACK involving "*adhesive*."

This "clip-strip" must be attached to your shirt(s) pocket before you get dressed and removed before you launder it. It is not visible and can be used a few times before it loses some usability.

Place **a length of cloth adhesive tape along the back of the top edge of your shirt pocket** to thicken the edge. Use a length of tape that is the width of the shirt pocket. The strip does not have to be very wide. One centre-meter is sufficiently wide.

Try it. Do the pen clips hold well enough to permit your normal activities without a problem? No? Try adding another strip to thicken it more.

This is an innocuous, practical answer that minimally compromises your convenience while confining the hassle to times of the day more under your control with anticipation of distractions and emergencies much lessened.

Answer (score 0):

Continue to do things exactly as you have been doing and things will continue to happen exactly as they have been happening. *Something* has to change in order for you to reasonably expect a change in outcome.

What are you willing to change? Convenience, attitude, behaviour, clothing style, equipment selection, what? For example, is your running style erratic? Could you learn to run in a more rhythmic and coordinated manner? Could you choose to wear military-style button-down flap-covered pockets? Could you decide to use more self-discipline (not run).

It is reasonable to remove your pens from your pocket prior to running or grovelling. Place them in a more secure alternate pocket or student paraphernalia. Remove them from one secure location to a more convenient one at an appropriate time. Take a moment prior to grovelling to thoughtfully remove distractions such as your pens and place them in a more appropriate place such as in your shoe.

It is reasonable to have or get duplicates for the occasions when they are necessary after running or grovelling. Keep duplicates and stand-by items with your other school supplies. Many students use a school bag or back-pack for extra items to keep them organized, handy, and easily transportable.

Forgetaboutit. It is reasonable to recover dropped items on rare occasions when they happen. It's part of the human journey and a bit of forbearance is a necessary ingredient.

Answer (score 0):

Tape will get covered with lint and will stop working in short time. Here's my suggestion:

Some pens are better than others at staying in place. Some of them, like this one:

[image]

have little "hooks" under the pocket clip that help it stay in place. The more common pens, like this one:

[image]

don't have those hooks and so only stay in place with the help of gravity. You can **add a hook** by **wrapping an elastic around the clip**.

**you can choose a smaller elastic band or one that matches the pen/shirt so it doesn't show as much. The size and color of this one are chosen so it's easy to see them in the pictures**

[image]

[image]

and voilà, your pen will stay in place once it's in your pocket.

**you can choose a smaller elastic band or one that matches the pen/shirt so it doesn't show as much. The size and color of this one are chosen so it's easy to see them in the pictures**