# How can I stop a comb from falling out of clothing pockets?

Tags: adhesive

My dad has a long habit of combing his hair every few hours, but all his shirts' and pants' pockets are open [as in this picture](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/18789/1869): no zippers or buttons to fasten the pocket.

[image]

While on the job, he can't carry a purse. It's obviously unproductive to add zippers to all his clothings' pockets. Too many combs have slid out of pockets, as he must frequently sit and get up. [A  retractable ski pass holder  'Skipasshalte'](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/a/6592/1869) doesn't appear to befit combs.

Comment: Anyone else read that product as a "Skip-ass halte?"

Answer (score 1):

A shorter comb will stay in place better. It will tend to sink to the bottom of the pocket and get somewhat suck, which is a good thing.

If he can't find a shorter comb, get a normal black plastic comb and saw it in half (since this is a lifehacks community!). Sand down the sawed edges so there aren't any jagged edges.

Answer (score 1):

Tie the comb to a small string, and attach to the other side a safety pin. You can then attach that pin to the shirt.

Answer (score 1):

Combs exist with a clip, similar to a pen, for helping hold a comb in the pocket:

https://kentbrushes.com/20t

[image]

Perhaps if you do not wish to purchase such, you could manufacture a similar one by attaching a clip off a pen lid, to an existing comb. The exact method of attachment would depend on the clip and the comb; perhaps if you find some you could post pictures of them up for more advice

Answer (score 0):

Attach a small fishing weight to a small comb by drilling a hole in the comb and using a key fob key ring. Put the comb in the pocket heavy side down. Hold the weighted end when using the comb